# QTableView, QStandardItemModel and Signals

Tags: qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel, qt-signals

I have a `QTableView`, populated with a `QStandardItemModel`.
I update the model frequently over network and the model is also updated by user directly via the `QTableView`.

Now I like to call a method when the user is changing some data, so i did:

```
connect(model, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)), this, SLOT(dataChanged(QStandardItem*)));
```

The Problem now is, that my `dataChanged` method is called, also when the item is updated over the network.

```
model->setData(index, new_val);
```

Is there another signal which is only emitted if, the user is changing something inside the `QTableview` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, AFAIK there is no such signal but you there is a way to hack it.

When editing an item from the `QTableView` the `activated` signal will have been emited. The idea is to catch this signal and connect it to a slot that will store the last manually changed item.

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(activated(QModelIndex), this, SLOT(manuallyActivated(QModelIndex)));

void manuallyActivated(QModelIndex index)
{
   // This variable should be in your header file...
   lastManuallyModifiedIndex = index;
}
```

Now simply modify your `dataChanged` slot to check if the item that changed corresponds to the last modified item.

```
void dataChanged(QStandardItem* item)
{
    // If it is invalid simply ignore it...
    if (lastManuallyModifiedIndex.isValid() == false)
        return;

    // only if it is modified manually we process it
    if (item->index() == lastManuallyModifiedIndex)
    {
        // make last modified index invalid
        lastManuallyModifiedIndex = QModelIndex();
        doSomething();
    }   
}
```

Comment: mhm looks like a nice workaround for my problem. after testing it, it looks like that the acivated signal is emited after selecting the item and hiting enter, but not by inline editing

Comment: i will keep ur answere, because its a accurate soloution, even the activate signal is not emited in my case (seams like its platform dependent)   i use now the entered signal and activated the mousetracking, wich is may not the best soloution, but it fit my needs)

Answer (score 1):

You could block the table signals when an update comes in from your network.

```
QObject::blockSignals(bool block)
```

or you could listen for click and edit event in succession.